# Bootstrap 3 / Knockout force navbar to collapse on mobile version of site

Tags: css, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used Knockout.js and added a click event to a href on the navbar of a site I'm working on. The click event works but one of the unfortunate side effects is that the navbar doesn't automatically close when using it on a mobile device.

Is there a way to "force" bootstrap to close the navbar after the Knockout function has completed?

--Updated--

I have tried returning true from the function in the ViewModel, and also from the function declaration on the href element, i.e.

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { doINeedToLogIn('bookings', data, event); return true; }">My Bookings</a>
```

but to no avail - the nav bar still refuses to close. I've also tried using a button in the navbar instead of a href element but it still does the same. Problem can be replicated if you shrink a desktop web browser right down so that the site goes "into" mobile mode (I know, I know).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to `return true` from your click binding handler.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work - please see my update.

Comment: Can you maybe create a simplified version of your navbar in a jsfiddle which demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple solution... But it works

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

add this where you want to trigger collapse...

```
$('button[data-toggle]').click()
```